# Horizontal Scrolling Menu (Manual)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Any existing libraries that can emulate or that are similar to the espn.com horizontal scrolling menu on their homepage (the first menu)? Sort of new to jquery and not sure where exactly to start. Searched google but didn't turn out fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some plugins for JQuery that should help you:

http://rascarlito.free.fr/hoverscroll/

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

http://www.tonylea.com/2011/jquery-horizontal-scrollbars/

Answer (score 0):

You can make horizontal scrolling menu themselves. It's very simple. 
[This](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/23/scroll-overflow-menu/) article explains how do it.
And [DEMO](http://darbybrown.com/menu/#)(Note: Reduce the size of the browser)